# Direction of change in Velocity Vector in Uniform Circular Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, centripetal-force

This is a snap of a textbook while describing Uniform Circular Motion.
For all the diagrams, and by the vector law, the directions of the del(v) vector is perfectly fine. But I am confused why this del(v) vector will always be pointing towards the center.

[image: NCERT Textbook]

As it is stated here, just because **v** is perpendicular to **r** and **v'** is perpendicular to **r'**, therefore del(v) is perpendicular to del(r) does not sound satisfactory.

Any other logical reason why del(v) vector will point towards center only when del(t) is long enough as in diagram a and b.

Comment: Will a mathematical proof satisfy you ? Then I can provide a simple one.

Comment: @BarunDasgupta yeah.

Comment: Ok , I misinterpreted your question. Let me provide the proof for the case where delta (V) is large.

Answer (score 1):

Is your question *why* the vector should be *radial* or you just don't understand why is it pointing *towards* the center instead of away from the center?
In the first case, simply, the difference of tangential vector is always radial, with respect to an origin of the reference frame which coincides with the center of the circle.
It originally comes from our "convention" to define counter-clockwise motion as motion with "positive velocity" i.e. on the way we define the signs of sine, cosine etc.

Let's see in math terms, but we need a bit of trigonometry (the simple kind):

We call **r** the vector going from the center to a point on the circle. It always points radially and outwards. For a point $P$ at an angle $\theta$ (using the usual convention of trigonometry where we start at $\theta=0$ for the $x$-axis and then go counter-clockwise..), then **r** is given by (assuming the radius is 1 for simplicity):

$$\textbf{r}=(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$$

At that same position, there is a tangential vector **t** such that $\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{t}=0$ (or rather, there are two, pointing in opposite direction). It's easy to see that

$$\textbf{t}=(-\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$$
(and you also have the opposite vector $-\textbf{t}$ of course, but by convention we use the first one).

You can quickly verify that it is perpendicular to the radius ($\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{t}=-\cos\theta\sin\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta=0). The reason we use this one and not its opposite is that in this way then tangent points in the same direction of a particle undergoing counter-clockwise motion - it's a convention).

Ok, now take two points $P$ and $P'$ at angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Their tangent (i.e., the velocities in your scheme) would be:

$$\textbf{v}=(-\sin\theta_1, \cos\theta_1)$$
and
$$\textbf{v'}=(-\sin\theta_2, \cos\theta_2)$$.

However, let's first simplify the situation as in your diagrams. The total angle between the two points is $\Delta\theta = \theta_2-\theta_1$ which is the case of uniform motion is $\Delta\theta =\omega\Delta t$.

The angle between the two vectors, i.e. the one bisecting $\Delta \theta$ is $\theta_m=(\theta_1+\theta_2)/2$. We then, as in your diagram, rotate our frame of reference so that $\theta_m=0$ i.e. the $x$-axis bisects $\Delta \theta$.
Because motion is uniform of course half of the total angle ($\Delta\theta/2$) will be below and half above.
Let me also fix the initial time as $t=0$ so that $\Delta t=t-t_0=t$ where $t$ is the elapsed time (for simplicity).
Notice that all of this does not change the generality of the solution as we can always make this rotation of the frame of reference by finding the center between any two points! Also, it works for long times and for short ones, as long as $\Delta\theta < \pi $ (it also work in that case but interpreting it becomes more wonky, so let us say both $P$ and $P'$ are on the right side of $x$-axis)

So, having said all that, we get

$$\theta_1=-\Delta\theta/2=-\omega t/2 $$ and
$$\theta_2=+\Delta\theta/2=\omega t/2$$

so we get
$$\textbf{v}=(-\sin\theta_1, \cos\theta_1) = (-\sin-\omega t/2, \cos -\omega t/2)$$
and
$$\textbf{v'}=(-\sin\theta_2, \cos\theta_2)= (-\sin \omega t/2, \cos\omega t/2)$$.

Usin some rules of sine and cosine for simplicity we can change some signs:

$$\textbf{v}= (\sin\omega t/2, \sin\omega t/2)$$
and
$$\textbf{v'}=(-\sin \omega t/2, \cos\omega t/2)$$.

So , let's compute the difference

$$\Delta\textbf{v}=\textbf{v'}-\textbf{v}=(-\sin\omega t/2-\sin\omega t/2, \cos\omega t/2-\cos\omega t/2) = (-2\sin\omega t/2, 0)$$

so you see immediately that the vector *only* has a $x$-component i.e. it is directed radially. Now, in which direction?

If $\omega>0$ (counter-clockwise motion) then $-2\sin\omega t/2<0$ hence the vector points in the negative $x$ direction. If instead the points are travelling in the opposite velocity $\omega<0$ then $-2\sin\omega t/2>0$ i.e. the vector points in the opposite direction.

So $\Delta\textbf{v}$ is always radial but its direction changes depending on in which order you take $P$ and $P'$. In the convention used by your book, we did as if motion were counter-clockwise so your vector points "towards the left" hence "towards the center".

Notice that all of this also depends on how you define your origin: in this case we have assumed it is in the center of the circle and everything works easily. But in general it could be anywhere. Vectors don't have a position in space, just a direction and a magnitude.

So, while the vector "stays the same" the way you "draw it" on the diagram or in space can change. Drawing the diagram as it is in the book helps visualizing the similarity between the triangles, but those triangles are not "physical" triangles, their position is arbitrary. Finding a position that helps understanding the math helps a lot, but it is not *the* position, is *a* possible one. Instead, the relationship between the vectors (if they are perpendicular, orthogonal, etc) instead is independent on the frame of reference and it is a *property* of the vector. But the position is not.

Comment: The whole point of the question is while del(t) is large, can we say that del(v) passes through center? As the position of the particle changes, so describing a force with a particular angle doesn't help.

Comment: The point is: del(v) does not "pass through the center", it does not have a "starting position", you can choose where to put del vs long as its length and orientation is always the same. You can draw the same scheme as in (a2) or (b2) of the book anywhere - the arrow will always be oriented that way but it may not pass through the center. However, drawing it in a specific position might help you notice geometrical features, for instance the similarity between triangles. What is *always* true is that del(v) is perpendicular to del(r) no matter where you put them.

Comment: However, if you put P and P' on the circle and draw a line connecting them (which is del(r) ) then del(v) will *always* be perpendicular to it. So, if you then put del(v) with its origin in the middle of del(r), then del(v) will be pointing towards the center, no matter the del(t). But you can freely choose to draw del(v) somewhere else and it will not point through the center. The only thing which are always true are the relative properties of the two vectors (del(v) and del(r) are always perpendicular) but their position in space depends on how you define the origin of the vectors.

Comment: So the "proof" is: del(v) is perpendicular to del(r). Draw P and P' on the circle. Draw del(r) connecting them. Draw del(v) in the middle of del(r) ---> then del(v) points towards the center.

Comment: This all makes more sense  when you put del(t) very small and then you can say that the acceleration is always perpendicular to the velocity (which is only well defined for del(t)<<1 ) meaning the acceleration is radial, which is the point the book is trying to make. A vector tangential on the circle and its derivative are always perpendicular, i.e. the velocity and the acceleration are perpendicular.

Comment: In other words: in the book del(v) is always towards the center because it is always drawn in a way that underlines the fact that it is perpendicular to del(r) (always true). If you draw it somewhere else, it still is perpendicular to del(r) but does not point towards the center anymore. However, it is the same vector! Drawing it there is just in order to clearly show the fact that they are perpendicular.

Comment: @JalfredP, Your answer provides a detailed and correct explanation. However your assertion that if v and v' are flipped then del v will point radially out is not correct. Even if you flip them, delv and hence acceleration will always be directed towards the center.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is if you compute v-v' instead of v'-v, so if you flip the order, not the arrows. I will fix the answer.

Comment: @JalfredP I got your point that del(v) and del(r) is perpendicular, but as you explained why del(v) is drawn so that it passes through center.

Comment: just to make the point clear and then use the similarity between triangles to show the intended result. The same would hold if drawn somewhere else, but drawing it there allows to immediately see the similarity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the small vector diagram to the right of the main diagram (b). You will see that the vector, $\Delta \mathbf v$ (shown in blue), is the vector which,  added to the 'initial' velocity, $\mathbf v$, makes the 'final' velocity, $\mathbf v'$. In other words,  $\Delta \mathbf v = \mathbf v'-\mathbf v$. You can see that $\Delta \mathbf v$, the change in velocity, is directed towards the circle centre.

Comment: As I said I have no confusion regarding the direction of del(v) vector. I am only confused why it is pointed to point C. Because if you take del(v) vector on a plane it can point to any direction.

Comment: For the arc PP', the directions of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf {v'}$ are fixed, as shown in diagram (a) or (b). But the direction of $\Delta \mathbf v$ is fixed in relation to those of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v'$, and you can see that its direction is towards the circle centre.

Comment: @soumyadip_poddar - because we're interested in the change when $\Delta t$ is very, very, very small. In that case, the two radius vectors will basically be right on top of each other (almost the same point), so $\Delta \vec v$ will be directed at C from that "common" point (in the limit).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović yes agreed. So the first two diagrams and the statement given to justify the direction of del(v) vector in the first two diagrams are misleading and wrong right?

Comment: The change in velocity vector is towards the circle centre even when $\Delta t$ is large. See diagram (b).

Comment: @soumyadip_poddar They are not strictly speaking wrong, but they are more meant to be visualised as steps towards the final diagram. (Imagine an animation starting with the first diagram, with the radius vectors getting closer and closer, so at some point becomes like the second diagram, and finally like the third one).

Comment: @PhilipWood can you explain this. I am not getting it. When del(t) is large, how does the del(v) still point towards center.

Comment: @PhilipWood why should we align the two vectors (v and v') in a way that del(v) points towards center. Why should we do that deliberately. Because if we place the del(v) vector of the first or second diagram at position P also we are not getting it directed towards center.

Comment: @PhilipWood - mathematically, geometric vectors don't have a starting position (just an endpoint), so you have to slide it somewhere. When $\Delta t$ is large, it's not going to point to the center unless you put it on the symmetry line as shown.

Comment: Again I refer you to diagram (b). In the little vector diagram to the right, $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v'$ are drawn in the directions of the velocities at  P and P'. So $\Delta \mathbf v$ (shown in blue) is in the correct direction with respect to the circle, that is towards the circle centre.

Comment: @Filip Milovanovi´c The vector diagram can be sited anywhere. It gives the direction of $\Delta \mathbf v$ relative to those of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v'$, and these are as shown on the circle diagrams.

Comment: @PhilipWood - yes, but the OP is asking is there any compelling reason why the (small/inset) diagram is placed so that when $\Delta \vec v$ is extended, it passes through $C$. Because, for example, if you root the diagram at $P$, it will miss C - except in the limit of small $\Delta t$.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović yes, exactly what I am asking.

Comment: Thank you. I've been very slow to grasp the point, which is that knowing the direction of a vector doesn't mean knowing that it is directed to a specific point in space. No doubt my claim that the result holds for a finite $\Delta t$ could be salvaged using an additional symmetry argument, but matters are not as straightforward as I was claiming.

Answer (score 0):

Since the motion is uniform circular , angular acceleration is 0 and r is constant. Now we will write position vector and velocity vector in polar coordinates.

[image]

This shows that **dv** always is radial and hence directed towards the center. Hope this clarifies and answers the question

When the delta (V) is large the following steps will lead to the proof.

[image]

Since we have not assumed anything about the del(time), this shows that the above is true even when del(time) is large. Hope this satisfies you.

Comment: Not satisfactory. As the proof you provided is for del(t) time, which caters to diagram (c) which is pretty clear and understandable. I was questioning about the first and second diagram when del(t) is pretty long.

Comment: I have added another proof for the case when del(t) is large.

Comment: Yeah but this explains the simple point that the direction of the vector in the 2D space irrespective of del(t) is correct as shown in all the 3 diagrams. But that doesn't answer my question that why should the vector always pass through the center C in diagram or origin O which you mentioned in the proof.

Comment: Moreover if you say that the del(v) and hence Force is at a theta/2 direction throughout the whole journey of the particle then there is no particle present till the particle reaches at theta/2 position. So no way, the force acts at Theta/2 angle during the total journey of the particle from r1 to r2. All this when del(t) is large.

Comment: The confusuion is because in maths a vector only has a magnitude and direction. There is an additional paramter for vectors in Physics. It is the point of application or a reference point. The impact of the vector to its surrounding depends on this point of application or the reference point. Here when you are describing a uniform circular motion, all the vectors associated with the motion has the center of the circle as its reference point. The velocity vector associated with the body in motion has **$wR$** as its magnitude and the direction is tangent to the circle about which it's rotating.

Comment: All the velcoity vectors in this particular case have at least 2 important reference points associated with them , they are the center of the circle and the point on the circle at the instant we are defining the velocity of the particle. This is important from Physics. If we place our velocity vectors at the points on the circle (Reference frame 1) the **del(v1)will always be radial implying that it passes through the center**. However from the point of view mathematics you can still place the velocity vectors any where in the plane (Reference frame 2) and calculate **del(v2)**

Comment: **Del(v)2** will be parallel to the **del(v1)** , but can pass through  different points implying a different impact on the environment. So in conclusion mathematically you are right that **del(v1)** vector doesn't pass through any particular point always, but while discussing Physics it's point of reference is important which is the center of the circle in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148084/discussion-between-barun-dasgupta-and-soumyadip-poddar).